# Can Openlayer 4 use the crs of GeoJson to reprojet on the fly

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I am reading from the server a GeoJson file with a crs definition:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32720" }     },                                                                               
"features": [ many features,.....
```

Then load it on the map, but it appear in another continent, near to greenwich meridian.

I read the docs and in many place there is a featureProjection option,
 but i don´t know if is for source or for target.

I try:

```
var vectorLayerUTMPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({            
        url: '/static/points.geojson',            
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:32720'}) //
    })
   });
```

Also:

```
var vectorLayerUTMPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({            
    url: '/static/points.geojson',            
    projection: 'EPSG:32720',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
})   });
```

The map load a OSM layer for reference and work good:

```
     var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
      vectorLayerUTMPoints
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
        collapsible: false
      })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```

The question is, OpenLayer 4 can read the crs definition from the geojson file and transform
to the crs of the view on he fly or how can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here: Firstly, the projection you're trying to use isn't included in OpenLayers by default: you have to import it using Proj4. I've taken code from [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html) to demonstrate.

First include the proj4 script and the definition of your projection from [EPSG.io](http://www.epsg.io):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.3/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://epsg.io/32720.js"></script>
```

You can now create an object holding a reference to your projection:

```
var myProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32720');
```

Your second issue is that you're using `featureProjection` incorrectly. There are two properties you need to set in the layer's `format` object: `dataProjection` is the projection of the data source, and `featureProjection` is what you want the features to be transformed to. In this case you want to transform them to fit your map projection, which is EPSG:3857.

So your code becomes:

```
var myProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32720');
var vectorLayerUTMPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({            
    url: '/static/points.geojson',            
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: myProj, featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}) 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I could not answer earlier because
i am stuck, you solution is very clear, but can´t make work.
The features are showed in the wrong place.

There is any way to know if the proj4 was properly loaded, it not have a isValid() method
or something like that.

I create a plunker file:[clik to see here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xFveclkXRJklIhPJnOaj?p=preview)

I try your sugestion, also:

```
   proj4.defs("EPSG:32720","+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");

 var sourceProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32720');
 var targetProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');   
 var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: sourceProj, featureProjection: targetProj'});

 var vectorLayerUTMPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({            
            url: '/static/centroids32720.geojson',            
            format: UTMFormat
        }),
    style: styleFunction    
   });
```

Also:

```
     proj4.defs("EPSG:32720","+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");  
 var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:32720', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
 var vectorLayerUTMPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({            
            url: '/static/centroids32720.geojson',            
            format: UTMFormat
        }),
    style: styleFunction    
   });
```

I see the points in FRANCE but there is not reprojection.

According to the api doc:

defaultDataProjection and featureProjection are a ol.ProjectionLike
It can be one of three things:
ol.ProjectionLike{ol.proj.Projection} {string} {undefined}

So the source is good.

Greetings